Alternatives to archive.php
Our site currently has a LOT of tags, which visitors get to via the main nav, sub nav, etc. This results in a LOT of tag/category pages.
The traditional paginated list of posts isn't a great user experience and ends up with pages looking very similar, especially if posts are cross-posted between tags, the similarity is more pronounced.
I've had some nice looking layouts designed, for example a 4-story block, amongst others and I'm thinking about how best to implement these and would like to know your opinions.
I was thinking for certain/selected tags, override the usual routing and display a page, which can display these blocks, either manually curated by the user or with shortcodes that pull posts in that meet certain criteria.
Curation of course presents a manual overhead, and I can't figure out how I'd implement pagination (E.g. if it's an infrequently updated tag page then this may only contain a nicely designed four posts on a tag page).
Even if I set a rule that said "this overridden tag page only displays 4 at a time" I'm not sure how to implement the loop/pagination on a per-tag basis.
Has anyone else solved this problem? Or do I need to think of another solution to display pages +1 ?
